# Relation between Eventhub topic partition count and spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, azure-eventhub

I am working on a spring boot cloud stream application that needs to read data from Azure Eventhub Namespace topic. I am trying to understand the relationship between Topic Partition count and `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency`.

If I will put partition count as 10 should I need to provide `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency` as 10 ? or there will be no impact if the value of these mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260536/spring-cloud-stream-spring-cloud-stream-default-consumer-concurrency-property-e).

In short:

If you have 10 partitions, and then set the concurrency as 10. Then there will 10 threads to read data from the 10 partitions.

And if you define concurrency less than 10, then there is at least 1 thread to read data from 2 partitions. This will cause a little performance issue.

Comment: Can this partition and concurrency mismatch result in much slowness? 
In my case I was reading a topic with 12 partitions but concurrency is set to 10 and the total data set is around 6500 but it took a day to complete the flow.

Comment: @RohailUsman, It will cause slowness. You'd better set it as 12 as well.

Comment: that's for sure I will set it to twelve but I was confused with a smaller number of records, how come the process is so much slower with 10 concurrency levels. Is there any document that can help me understand it better?